# БСП неоднородное?

Tags: бсп

Кто из них забил овечку раньше, уже не узнаешь: обезглавленное животное валялось тут же, втоптанное в грязь, багровея боком.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) БСП могут быть однородного или неоднородного состава.

БСП однородного состава составлены из равноправных предложений (без подчинения), обычно это значение перечисления или сопоставления: Шумел ветер, гремел гром. Ты прозаик, я - поэт.

БСП неоднородного состава - это аналоги придаточных предложений (условие, время, причина и т.д).

2) Кто из них забил овечку раньше, уже не узнаешь: обезглавленное животное валялось тут же, втоптанное в грязь, багровея боком.

Здесь бессоюзная связь между СПП со значением изъяснения и простым предложением. Скорее всего, это не тема однородных и неоднородных БСП.

Comment: В общем-то парень он способный, хоть и похабник – таскает с собою ворох развратных открыток.

Это подходит к БСП?

Comment: Да, это неоднородное БСП,  второе предложение поясняет первое, между предложениями причинно-следственная связь.

Comment: спасибо вам за ответ!